# Python: how to separate certain number-text combination from string?

Tags: python

for example: a=['Now is 20m before 10h','OK 15s after 6 punctual']. I want time_fragment=['20m','15s'].

I've seen answers that used split function and import re, but didn't see anything to address a number-text combination case. This has a bit text mining involved so the data is messy.

Comment: Split *can* be used to separate individual words, whether they have numbers in them or not.  Until you specify what kind of pattern you are looking for and/or how to identify it, and not just a single example with no explanation, not sure how much help you will get.

Comment: making adjustments to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the times before the word "before", you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in you regex.

```
import re
s = 'Now is 20m before 10h'
rgx = re.compile(r'[0-9]+[hms](?= *before)')
print rgx.findall(s) # ['20m']
```